# How to update a chart on prop change in vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

First, I would like to emphasize that I am a completely new to Vue (and webdev in general).

I have to make a UI where I have to show some data that I fetch from an API. But I have some issues with chart.js: I can't update my chart when prop change.
Currently, I have the following setup:

Card.vue:

```
<script>
    import DoughnutChart from './DoughnutChart.js'
    export default {
        name: 'Card',
        components: {
            DoughnutChart
        },
        props: ['scheda'],
        created() {
            console.log(this.scheda)
        }
    }
</script>
<template>
   <DoughnutChart type="abcd" :chartData="this.scheda"/>
</template>
```

DoughnutChart.js:

```
import { defineComponent, h } from 'vue'

import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ArcElement,
    CategoryScale
} from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale)

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'DoughnutChart',
    components: {
        Doughnut
    },
    props: ['type', 'chartData'],
    setup(props) {
      const chartData = {
      labels: ['A', 'B'],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ["#ff3333", "#131b2e"],
          cutout: "75%",
          borderWidth: 0,
          data: [props.chartData.value, (100 - props.chartData.value)]
        }
      ]
    }  
    const chartOptions = {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }  
    return () =>
      h(Doughnut, {
        chartData,
        chartOptions
      })
  }
})
```

`this.scheda` is a reactive value and when it changes the chart should update accordingly.

I have read the [documentation](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts), but I simply can't wrap my head around it.
I have also tried searching on the internet, but all examples reference the older version of the chart library.
Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a chart js and integrate with view, you can create your `canvas` on js outside of vue js flow, and then get the element reference inside vue and then integrate it, the big problem rendering components inside vue is that you need update your charts, it may cause unexpected behavior on canvas. Because tools like Vue are designed to refresh the html and canvas always are a single html tag with a lot of interactivity in js(not much html).

### Vue-chart

You can install
[vue-chart.js](https://vue-chartjs.org/)

It supports data updates and also you can access to the chart ref.

**Updating charts:** https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts

**Acesing to ref:** https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#access-to-chart-instance